# Increase clearance between tire and frame

Tags: tire, rims

The tire on my bicycle rim slightly touches parts of my frame. Obviously, the rims are too large for my frame. However, is it possible to get tires with a lower "height" (see red arrow in the picture) to increase the clearance between tire and the frame (0.5 cm would be sufficient)? If yes, for what do I have to pay attention when buying a tire? Any other suggestions on how to solve this problem without buying new rims?

[image]

Comment: Usually the width roughly corresponds to the height. You can’t just get “lower” tires. How did you end up in this situation? Did you actually install wheels with a greater diameter? (e.g. went from 559mm (26") or 584mm (27.5") to 622mm (28")) Did you install wider tires? Or is your wheel out of true?

Comment: What is the exact ETRTO code from the sidewall of your tyres?   it will be in the format xx-yyy or yyy-xx where yyy is the diameter in mm of the rim, and the xx is the diameter of the tyre in mm.  This will tell us the size of your rim.

Comment: Also, if you know it, the internal rim width would be useful.  This will help identify the range of tyre widths that this rim should be used with.   Its possible someone has fitted a much wider tyre than the rim width allows, giving a "pointy" fitting.

Comment: It should be noted that if the problem is with the rear wheel, then it's possible that the axle is not properly seated all the way back in the dropouts.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible that your rims are not too large for the frame, you are just using tires that are too wide and tall than the frame was designed to accommodate.

Tire height is related to width, you can't specifically get a tire that is shorter. YOu just need to drop down to the next lower tire size. E.g., if your tires are nominally 32mm wide try 28mm tires.

There are only a few rim diameters in common use on new bicycles [559mm, 584mm, 622mm) it would be obvious if you had the wheels that were larger than the frame is designed for. Possibly though you have older 630mm rims a frame designed for 622mm.

Comment: Agreed - I'm seeing a rim brake track, and it's pretty unlikely that OP has somehow got larger rims, with the one exception of 622mm to 630mm, an increase of 4mm on radius.

Comment: The rest of the bike isn't shown in the photo, but quite a few road bikes between 80s and early 2000s were designed for 23mm tires and didn't have much clearance for larger ones.

Comment: Agreed. Although one could swap between 630 and 622 mm rims, there aren't a lot of alternative rim sizes that will work with existing rim brakes.